# Implementation of Haskell's forkIO

Tags: haskell, concurrency

Different OSes have different concurrency subsystems, there are OS processes, POSIX threads and today also "LWP" threads in Linux, Windows has processes, fibers, threads, etc. Each process is scheduling by OS scheduler and gets own quantum of CPU time. This is true for Linux "LWP"s because they are processes but sharing memory space, and it's not true for user-space threads, where all threads share one CPU time quantum.

Haskell has forkIO. I found in the Haskell sources next commentaries:

> Scheduling of Haskell threads is done internally in the Haskell
>   runtime system, and doesn't make use of any operating system-supplied
>   thread packages.

also

> In terms of performance, 'forkOS' (aka bound) threads are much more
>   expensive than 'forkIO' (aka unbound) threads, because a 'forkOS'
>   thread is tied to a particular OS thread, whereas a 'forkIO' thread
>   can be run by any OS thread.  Context-switching between a 'forkOS'
>   thread and a 'forkIO' thread is many times more expensive than between
>   two 'forkIO' threads.

which emphasizes that threads created with `forkIO` are not scheduling by the OS scheduler. They, as I understand, can be free from common blocking (with `-thread` option, sure), but however in the case there are 3 open questions for me:

1. how do they ("threads" created with forkIO) share those CPU quantum?
2. will they be guaranteed to be distributed to different cores or, since they are represented by one process, no? Or is this non-deterministic behavior?
3. Am I right that to avoid interference effects is better to use `forkOS` than `forkIO`? I mean if I have 2 threads and one of them serves HTTP and another one makes heavy disk I/O operation, then better solution will be to use `forkOS` than `forkIO`?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Because there is an excellent paper which is very approachable and goes into great detail on exactly these questions linked in the documentation.

Comment: And pulling in that line of documentation to make this conversation more self-contained: "The concurrency extension for Haskell is described in the paper Concurrent Haskell http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/papers/concurrent-haskell.ps.gz"

Comment: @DanielWagner would you point out documentation link where to read about sharing of the CPU quantum between unbound Haskell threads? I can not find any Haskell documentation about such low details, but I have feeling that all "magic" is reducing to POSIX threads in the implementation that are started as LWP (bound) or user-space threads (unbound). Right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Little testing on Windows 10 with 4 core CPU shows results:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent

t1 = forever $ print "1"
t2 = forever $ print "2"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  t1id <- forkOS t1 -- I tried forkOS and forkIO
  t2id <- forkOS t2
  getLine
  putStrLn "Done"
```

Both, `forkIO` and `forkOS` requires `ghc-options: -threaded` option to utilize mutli-thread execution. In both cases I see only one OS process, but multiple threads. In the case of `forkIO` threads number is 4, while in the case of `forkOS` I get only 3. More interesting is the number of context switches, it's different from mentioned suggestions: in the case of `forkIO` they are (for different threads): 480000 and 48... and in the case of `forkOS` they are about 2, 3, 16 for the same time period. This means that `forkIO` makes more context switches than `forkOS` (**hundreds of thousands vs tens**) and summary execution time of the same valuable effect should be greater, so `forkOS` looks more preferable on Windows box.

As I see in GHC source code, POSIX threads are using under the hood.

**EDIT**. Linux test (`ps -eLf`):

forkOS:

```
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
...        ...   ...   ... ... ...   ... ...           ... ...
xyz     7432  4865  7432  0    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     7432  4865  7448  0    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     7432  4865  7449  0    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     7432  4865  7450  0    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     7432  4865  7451 66    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:06 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     7432  4865  7452  0    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     7432  4865  7453 67    7 10:03 pts/0    00:00:06 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
```

forkIO:

```
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
...        ...   ...   ... ... ...   ... ...           ... ...
xyz     8209  4865  8209  0    6 10:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     8209  4865  8225  0    6 10:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     8209  4865  8226  0    6 10:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     8209  4865  8227  0    6 10:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     8209  4865  8228 99    6 10:08 pts/0    00:00:06 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
xyz     8209  4865  8229  0    6 10:08 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/xyz/prj/thr/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.25/8.6.5/bin/yohoho
```

In Linux in `forkIO` case we have only 6 LWPs and one of them utilizes CPU on 99%. In the case of `forkOS` we have 7 LWPs, and 2 of them utilize CPU on about 66%, which from my point of view, looks better. So, seems that `forkOS` is more preferable in Linux too.

Comment: "more preferable" for what? 2 indefinitely spinning tasks isn't really the scenario a work stealing scheduler is optimised for, true, but it's also not really a common IRL scenario.

Comment: Without proper profiling (in addition to this 'benchmark'), it does not make sense to say that "forkOS is more preferable" for any kind of circumstances.

If we were to speculate here, then in an IO-only 'computation' (such as writing to `stdout` continuously) it might make sense that `forkOS` has better performance, yet it does not make sense to extrapolate this conclusion to any kind of situation.
What can be under the question here is how GHC deals with concurrent usage of handles, i.e. I bet that `print` does not map to a single `write(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Haskell threads use cooperative multi-threading. Essentially, each time Haskell needs to allocate memory, it checks if enough time has passed, and if so it switches to the next thread. The exact mechanism is a bit more sophisticated (I think at some point it also involved POSIX signals e.g. 'alarm'), but this should be the main idea.
2. The runtime system makes N Haskell threads run over K OS threads. K can be chosen by the user. It's the OS which then decides on which core(s) each OS thread is run -- this might always be the same core or not.
3. IO heavy operations should not be a big issue. The Haskell runtime uses nonblocking IO and poll/select to multiplex IO over all threads. Also, if you have two running Haskell threads and you dedicate at least two OS threads to the runtime, these should be run over the OS threads, which the OS should allocate to both cores. Feel free to experiment with`forkIO` vs `forkOS` to see which provides the best performance for your case, but `forkIO` should be better in virtually all cases.

Comment: Is there *any* performance benefit to `forkOS`? I was under the impression that `forkOS` is exactly like `forkIO`, except the created thread is not allowed to move between OS threads, which seems like it can only be slower (unless there's some other cost for moving between OS threads).

Comment: @HTNW Probably there isn't. Edited.

Comment: @HTNW "slow" is sense of context switching? It's different

Comment: About 2. If the threads are user-space, how OS can sparse them on OS processes? What library is using under the hood? POSIX threads? Did you mean bound threads only?

Comment: Bound threads aren't any faster. They're often slower, in fact, as they can't move between capabilities in the work-stealing queues. The only thing bound threads buy you is compatibility with libraries that use thread-local data, as they guarantee all FFI calls from them will come from the same native thread.

Comment: >"Bound threads aren't any faster" - what kind of "speed" do you mean? Context switching? Because it's just process and CPU executes it's machine instructions as anything else. Unbound threads are just user-space POSIX threads that do share OS scheduler resource which is bad. OS processes allow maximal isolation (avoid of interferences), so they have own OS schedule resource, are always planning on all cores, etc. I found here question about forkIO where one unbound thread blocked all other with `-thread` option due to heavy loading: seems there are interferences: just pthreads are under hood